# How to use #load in scriptcs for an Azure function

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, scriptcs

I downloaded the code of an Azure Function created in the portal. Now I'm tryng to load a class in the main file (run.csx) using in the first line:

```
#load "..\shared\data.csx"
```

but i get the error:

```
 "run.csx(1,7): error CS1504: Source file '..\shared\data.csx' could not be opened -- Could not find file."
```

I added in the host.json:

```
"watchDirectories": [ "Shared" ]
```

I tried with uppercase, lowcase, put the class in the same folder of the run.csx but it doesn't work. I miss something?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot of your folders from Kudu file explorer?

Answer (score 1):

Double check that your "Shared" folder is under `D:\home\site\wwwroot\Shared`. Note that the root of your function app is at `D:\home\site\wwwroot`.

Comment: my "Shared" folder is at the same level of the function folder (the one that contain run.csx) but i don't know how to check if it is in "D:\home\site\wwwroot"

Comment: You can see your Function App files in [Kudu](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-how-to-use-azure-function-app-settings#kudu). Try going to `https://<myfunctionapp>.scm.azurewebsites.net/`, which is just your function app url with ".scm." inserted in the middle. Then, go to "Debug console" and you'll be at the Kudu file explorer Mikhail was asking about!

Comment: Also - if your "Shared" folder is at the same level of the _function_ folder, where run.csx is, then i think you should be referencing `#load ".\shared\data.csx"`